# How to handle Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: err is not defined when Sequelize with Node?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My code

```
const connection = new Sequelize('db','miki','passw', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect : 'sqlite',
    storage: 'db.sqlite',
    operatorsAliaases :'false'
})

const user = connection.define('User', {
    name : Sequelize.STRING,
    bio : Sequelize.TEXT 
});

connection.sync({
    logging : console.log
})
.then(() => {
    User.create({
        name: 'Beba',
        bio: 'devops engineer'
    })
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connectio to db established');
})
.catch(() => {
    console.error('unable to connect to db', err);
});
```

I got error

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255), `bio` TEXT, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Users`)
Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: err is not defined
```

I looked at similar SO posts but the answers suggest to rewrite the code with promises. Is there any simple solution with sync to catch the error when adding items to database?

Comment: try replacing .catch((err) => {
    console.error('unable to connect to db', err);
});

Comment: It does not help, unable to connect to db ReferenceError: User is not defined.

Comment: It does man , It tells you `User.create` that you are using upper case. It does man.

Comment: Yeah,you can post an answer.

Comment: no issue, I am happy if it resolves your issue, you can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pass err parameter through catch function 
.catch((err) => {
    console.error('unable to connect to db', err);
});
```